# Get tab when mouse is over

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I would like to know if is there any way to get the tab id which mouse is over using javascript?
I want to get the html from page and show in a separate div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not possible. There is no publicly available type of event, that would make it possible:
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#global-events